# CIFS Volume mounting problem

Tags: linux, debian, centos, mount

When I ran this command

mount -t cifs //192.168.10.1/ycw /mnt -o rw,user=testuser,password=testpass

I got mount error 112 "Host is Down" when tried to do directory mount from Debian machine to Centos machine.

Can anyone have idea to resolving this mount problem?

Waiting for the reply.

Jaby

Answer (score 1):

Some questions:

- Can you ping 192.168.10.1?
- Can you access the share using [smbclient](http://us6.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html)?
- As mentioned by Kyle, is there anything in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

Did you umount and then mount again?  When you do this does mount give any errors or are there any error messages from the command 'dmesg' or in /var/log/messages?